# Can't seem to build elevation with the wingcap

Tags: super-mario-64

I'm using the wingcap in Mario 64 and can't build elevation. I seem to naturally lose elevation. I attempt to recover elevation by swooping. I hold down for about 2 seconds and then up and get a boost. Any less time spent holding down and the swoop doesn't boost me. But each time I swoop I seem to lose more elevation than I gain! The downwards part of the swoop doesn't seem to be counteracted by the upwards swoop or perhaps there is something else going on.

Comment: I think this is possible somehow, but involves "out of bounds" and is a TAS-only, very precise trick. Pannenkoek2012 used it once.

Comment: @FabianRöling I've edited my answer to link a high-speed wingcap TAS.

Answer (score 2):

That's just how the Wing Cap works. You will gradually lose elevation over time while flying. The only way to reset this ([outside of glitches](https://youtu.be/LZrbdRm8p9E?si=uP3x6wsPKTsEAVnJ)) is to restart your flight from a high point either by cannon or triple jump.